# Can't edit the text using the React AceEditor

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

```
<div
 ref='ace'
>
    
  <AceEditor
    ref='ace'
    mode="markdown"
    theme="textmate"
    onChange={this.handleMarkdownChange}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    showGutter={false}
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
    value={this.state.markdownSource}
    readOnly={false}
    onLoad={this.setEditor}
  />
</div>
```

I am using React AceEditor. It's weird that I cannot even trigger the `onChange` event. I can click and and I see the text cursor, but when I try to type it, nothing happens. Does it have anything to do with the `ref`?

Comment: May be a full or minimal replicatable example would help. but i am attaching a working example as answer

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working example.

[image: Edit react-select-test (forked)]

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      aceValue:""
    }
  } 

  onChange=(newValue)=> {
    console.log('change', newValue);
    this.setState({
      aceValue:newValue
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Ace Editor</h1>
        <AceEditor
          mode="plain_text"
          theme="github"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.aceValue}
          name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
          showGutter={false}
          wrapEnabled={true}
          highlightActiveLine={false}
          editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
          enableBasicAutocompletion={true}
          enableLiveAutocompletion={true}
          setOptions={{
            enableSnippets: true,
            // fontFamily: "tahoma",
            fontSize: "10pt"
          }}
        />
      </div>
      
  }
}
```